# On Home or Question page show close/reopen status

Tags: feature-request, questions, homepage, questions-page

It'd be nice for questions that have close or reopen votes to show that on the home or questions page, maybe like this pic:

[alt text http://img35.imageshack.us/img35/4397/sotoclose.png](http://img35.imageshack.us/img35/4397/sotoclose.png)

**EDIT:**  This would only show for the 3k+ users who could vote to open or close.

Comment: related - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88832/show-number-of-reopen-votes-for-in-closed-questions-titles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That information is intentionally left out - it's either open or closed, and in order to find out the number of votes in any direction one must open the question and at least run their eyes over the actual content to get to the part that shows them if people are voting to open or close.

10K+ reputation tools have insight into this, though, so this is a feature already reserved for higher rep users.

Comment: Can't wait til I get there.

Answer (score 3):

10K users can see lists of questions with open/close votes. I'm not sure we need to increase the exposure of this to all users.

Answer (score 1):

I got here because I was writing exactly the same proposal. I do believe it would be a good tool to have. The info is already available for 3K+ users when opening the question, and it seems that it's also available to 10K+ users on a list, so why not making the info more available to 3K+ users then?

There are many duplicate/poor questions that remain alive (and sometimes gather duplicate answers) just because not enough users with close vote power actually *read* the question. This way it might speed up the process.