# Show close-vote count for questions on main list

Tags: feature-request, voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [On Home or Question page show close/reopen status](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35690/on-home-or-question-page-show-close-reopen-status)

Would it be possible to show how many close-votes have been cast against a question when viewing the main list of questions on the site?

That would allow people to quickly determine which questions they should review and cast a vote if needed (without having to click on each question individually)

**Example:**

[alt text http://img.skitch.com/20100518-cpu1g4m6ute7d6atexs25pps6k.jpg](http://img.skitch.com/20100518-cpu1g4m6ute7d6atexs25pps6k.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

I would rather not see this.  I think it would encourage premature closing of questions (which is, arguably, already a problem).  The 10K tools have a list of questions with the highest close votes already.  I say keep it there in the 10K tools.  These users are considered the most trusted to cast the votes appropriately and as such get the tools to help expedite that.