# Show number of reopen votes for in closed questions titles

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen

Sometimes it happens that a question is closed hastily. Either some information was missing, but was later added, or because some (5) people did not understand an unclear (but still understandable question), or because some users followed other users' decision to close (because they are popular, for example).

In all cases, if the question does not really 'deserve' to be closed, there is the reopening process. I don't know what's the statistics, but I don't think it's too often that a question is reopened.

One of the reasons (apart from the obvious - that the question really deserves closing) is that people don't bother opening closed questions - that is, questions with `[closed]` in their titles.

My suggestion is to add the number of reopen votes to the title, so that people know that there's still 'hope' for that question, rather than ignoring it. For example `[closed, 2 reopen votes]`

Comment: Just a note: [closed] is visible for all, but close/reopen votes are not visible to those without privileges.

Comment: fine, then the title can be conditional. Not too much of an issue, I believe.

Comment: I hope so. And you may interest this request too - [Make close votes live for a given number of views rather than given time.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87979/make-close-votes-live-for-a-given-number-of-views-rather-than-given-time)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35690/on-home-or-question-page-show-close-reopen-status

Answer (score 2):

In theory, there's always hope for the question. You can always browse to a question with `[closed]` in the title and cast a vote to re-open it.

The only thing your suggestion would accomplish is reinforcing the very same bad behavior that you decry in the first place. In particular, by placing the number of re-open votes in the question title (`[closed, 2 reopen votes]`), it would encourage people to open those questions just so that they could cast their *own* vote to re-open the question. That's exactly the same mentality as that which you finger as leading to "hasty" question closures—users blindly following other users' decision to close:

> "Sometimes it happens that a question is closed hastily  [ . . . ]  because some users followed other users' decision to close (because they are popular, for example)."

I agree that closing questions should not be a popularity contest, but I think the same should apply to
re-opening questions, as well. I struggle to see any other advantage to be gained from including this information in the question's title.

This information is always available *after you open* the question, which is the only time that you can really make an informed decision about whether or not that question deserves to be re-opened. You have to look at the content of the question itself in order to determine if it has really improved enough to merit it being re-opened. Having the information in the question title at best clutters up the search page with additional noise, and at worst, encourages the very same behavior that you seek to discourage in the first place (albeit in reverse).