# Can we show the number of pending close votes in a question's title?

Tags: feature-request, questions, vote-to-close

After casting a [close (as duplicate) vote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182161/get-quotes-from-google-finance-yahoo-finance) for a question today it struck me: we see the text `[closed]` in the question title when a question has been closed, so why can't we also see the number of **pending close votes** at the moment the page is rendered?

**What will this achieve?**
This brings it to people's attention faster, and should lead to questions being closed faster, and having a shorter Review queue overall.

Currently users have to visit either the `flags` or `close` tabs on the Review page to get a list of questions with close votes. If a question is not attracting a lot of attention (because of its title/summary and it hasn't been up/down voted), and few people are monitoring the Review page at the time then a question can languish for some time. (Note that the example question still only has two close votes and a mere 25 views after 6 hours).

It seems to me to be a relatively simple feature to implement, and you could possibly restrict showing it to only those with the [3000 rep](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) required to close questions.

As an example, here is a mock-up of the actual question I voted to close:

[image]

- *Apologies for the lack of free hand circles - to make up for that transgression I have used wiggly arrows instead*

A similar feature has been suggested before, but for reopen votes: [Show number of reopen votes for in closed questions titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88832/show-number-of-reopen-votes-for-in-closed-questions-titles)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No.**

The information in the title is pure noise. We already have a problem with people ignoring closed questions at large, when in many cases all they need is some edit love, I'm afraid with your feature people will start ignoring questions with 3 or 4 close votes as well.

If the problem is that not many people monitor the review close queue, well, good news, the review tasks are being [revamped](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137174/new-feature-community-review-tasks). And if you think a question has escaped for far too long and there's little chance it would be closed naturally, then you can simply flag it for moderation attention.

Comment: +1 - There is also the opposite effect: People may be on the "hunt" for questions that they can close, and this may cause more people to jump on the closing bandwagon.

Comment: @jmort253 Yes. I've closed over 2K questions on Programmers, I don't think anyone wants to make it easier for me ;)

Comment: I've had a play with the new review tasks - the layout is not initially obvious (had to stop and think for a moment), feels a bit like a psych test and I'll get a rating at the end. If you consider my suggestion adds noise to the title then I hope the `[closed]` addition will disappear, or the closed question itself is removed from the list.

Comment: @slugster The new review tasks are a work in progress, please do post any issues as an answer in the Meta q. Having [closed] in the title is not the same as having [3], the difference being that a question with 3 close votes is _not_ closed and you can't even safely assume it will be closed.